# Elapsed Time with Joda-Time

Tags: jodatime

I have a [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object that I need to see if it's 10 years or more in the past (Think of expiring certifications). I'm new to [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), how is that done? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to review the [docs for the DateTime class](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html). But just to get you moving, the check would look something like the following:

1) You'll need to construct a DateTime which represents 10 years ago...

```
// Build a DateTime for exactly 10 years ago.

DateTime tenYearsAgo = new DateTime(); // should give you a DateTime representing 'now' 
tenYearsAgo = tenYearsAgo.minusYears(10);            // should give you 10 years ago
```

2) ...and use DateTime.isBefore to compare.

```
// Let's assume the DateTime you're comparing is called 'myDateTime'.

if (myDateTime.isBefore(tenYearsAgo)) { /* do something */ }
else { /* do something else */ }
```

Note there are some subtleties with calendars which Joda does a nice job of abstracting for you; before you get too deep in this, you'll really want to study the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with joda.
See if `Years.yearsBetween` helps (link below).

It might look like `Years.yearsBetween(myDateTime, new DateTime());`

[1] http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Years.html#yearsBetween(org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant)